# how to add video properties while downloading

Tags: html

i visited g2g.fm, a site for downloading movies. They claim that they do not store those movies on their servers. But when you download a movie (mp4) it already comes with properties added. And the comment property as there url address.

What i want to know is. Is their a code you place on html, that adds properties while the user is downloading the video link taken from another site like g2g.fm ?

Im building a blog of my own. And i index links from other sites. Problem is, those files from other sites come with properties added and there url .

Comment: I don't know that there *is* a way to modify a video file using a simple HTML tag. Seems to me you'd need to so something to it on the server side, [using a tool like ffmpeg](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=43048) to set the metadata fields.

Comment: I posted a link in my comment to an ffmpeg syntax example for setting metadata. All you would have to do is integrate that into a server-side script, then dump the contents of the file to the browser. If you need help doing that, search this site because I'm sure it's been asked and answered here before.